# Unable to connect to MY SQL DB in Ajax call using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am performing a DB operation after making an ajax call using php, 
1) I see in fiddler that the request and response to the PHP (ajax call) are fine but and 2) I see the error "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO" in Fiddler.

I am not trying to connect to root but to a different user.
Here is the view.php file where ajax call is initiated:

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: 'delete_entry.php',
     data: "id="+del_id,
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
             alert("Success");
                  //document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = output;
              }
});
```

I recieve the alert message "Success" though.

Code in delete_entry.php:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "testdb";
    $password = "testdb";
    $dbname = "testts";


    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        echo "Connection Failed";
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

$id=$_POST['id'];
echo $id;  // I get a proper Id here
$delete = "DELETE FROM ExpenseTable WHERE Id='"+$id+"'";
$result = mysql_query($delete) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Please help as I do not understand why the mysql db is trying to connect to root eventhough I specify the db detais as "testdb".
I am able to connect to the same db with these credentials in my view.php

Comment: Just a wild guess: Try reloading several times. The browser might cache.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using your created DB connection when you pass the sql query to the DB. Use the mysqli_query method as below..

```
mysqli_query($conn,$delete);
```